# Advanced Search Link

Tags: search

I have enabled the link to Advanced Search from Home Page just beside the searchinput box. I want to style this link and change the colors. Please let me know how do I do this?

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you running?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to override the CSS for the link, but as I'm not sure which version of SharePoint you're running, I can't be more specific.

Your best bet would be to use an inspector tool for whatever browser you're using (Firebug, IE Developer Tools, etc) and select the Advanced Search link element. This will tell you which CSS class to change.

Comment: SharePoint 2010